# Maintaining Internal Order Statuses Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento2

We are evaluating Magento for an Ecommerce Solution. The Magento solution is customized to connect to a bunch of internal systems for payment, order processing and other functionalities.

We are planning to use a few External Order Status and Internal Order Status to handle the System workflow from one integration to another. The Strategy is that Internal Statuses are internal for our support and customer sees external statuses, together they help us identify closure of each state(e.g. payment success ) and then navigate to the next step (Order creation ). Reason to do this way is that, most of internal service needs retry mechanisms and other batch options.

### Question

1. is there an existing table in DB that we can reuse for Internal Status scenario?.
2. We need to query and also keep a tab for all the internal statuses the user has passed through. What is the easy way to achieve this?.

Please let me know, so i can find the best way to implement this solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Magento statues are stored in `sales_order_status`. You can create, manage and assign them to states in System->Order Statuses
2. Status changes are usually tracked in order history `sales_flat_order_status_history`